# Can I run XCode for iOS development in plain leopard?

Tags: xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios, ios-simulator, osx-leopard

I am aware that I cannot actually distribute an app that is not compile with the latest version, but I cannot upgrade my Mac now for some driver compatibility issue.

So, for the time being, is there any way to do actaully code and test an iphone app in plain old leopard? I cannot find what I need to download in the dev center.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit2: peter.boctor.net/2010/06/24/older-versions-of-xcode-iphone-sdk

Edit: nvm, I think it might not include iPhone SDK...

Log in to connect.apple.com and go to downloads -> developer tools.

There you will find older versions of XCode. The earliest I can find is 3.1. I think that will work on Leopard.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems 3.1.2 runs on Leopard. Will the iPhoneSDK be compatible with it? Or is there a special download for that too?

Comment: I found a site after some searching: http://peter.boctor.net/2010/06/24/older-versions-of-xcode-iphone-sdk/